# Lightning Connect - OData Service

Tags: lightning-connect, odata

Has anyone used Apache Olingo to create a OData service to expose Oracle database.

Comment: Vidya, welcome to SFSE. I suggest you try to provide a little more detail, and narrow your post down to one specific question that the community can help you resolve. As it's written, this question is very broad.

Comment: I am trying to use Lightning connect for our integration. We are trying to create OData service to expose Oracle database to SF. We are not interested in using a third party to do this. I created the WCF data service, but had some issues. SF suggested that I use apache Olingo to create the OData.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of setting up Olingo with a JPA provider: http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/02/05/odata-producer-using-apache-olingo-with-mysql-jpa-tomcat-web-server

The blog mentions MySQL but you can use any database.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence. All my searches point to this link. Although it doesn't specify it works for Oracle, like you said I will try it and test it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Olingo is definitely one of the most popular libraries to produce/consume OData. You can also consider a 3rd party tool such [DataDirect's Connectivity Services](https://www.progress.com/cloud-and-hybrid-data-integration) that let you implement OData from popular databases. Here is their [Oracle OData page](https://www.progress.com/odata/oracle-database).

Disclaimer: Please note that I do product marketing for Progress DataDirect. Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If you have any affiliation with a supplier that you are recommending please make it clear in your answer. See [answer]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Dave. I added the suggested changes.